# plotting histogram as line graph in matplot using x and y values in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, linegraph

I have two input values for X-axis and Y-axis.
I would like to plot a histogram as a line graph.  An example is provided in the attached image.
I am not able to plot a histogram using these values.

```
ys = [0.21428571428571427, 0.14285714285714285, 0.047619047619047616, 0.11904761904761904, 0.09523809523809523, 0.09523809523809523, 0.023809523809523808, 0.09523809523809523, 0.11904761904761904, 0.047619047619047616]

xs = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I tried

```
plt.hist(xs,ys)
plt.show()
```

but it failed.

I am interested in a graph like the following, preferably with and without the line on the histogram.

[image].

The X and Y axis are assigned with values of xs and ys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you need is [`bar`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar). 
Here's a minimal example:

```
>>> bar(xs, ys, width=1, align='center', color='brown')
>>> plot(xs, ys, color='purple', lw=2, marker='s')
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work. how can I just create the line graph.(no histogram at all)

Comment: @user1988876 The call to `plot` does this. What do you mean "did not work"? The calls need to correspond to the imports you made. According to the code in your question, it should be `plt.bar` and `plt.plot`. Don't forget to `plt.figure()` and `plt.show()` if you do it non-interactively, but this is the basic stuff I assume you know.

Comment: Please note a histogram is a different thing from a bargraph!

Comment: @Dan Sure. But if you have `x` _and_ `y` you probably want the latter.